# Smoothness of solutions to a system of functional equations

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a system of $n-1$ equations involving $n$ variables. Each variable is defined on `nice' intervals (e.g., open intervals), all the functions $f_1, \cdots, f_{n-1}$ are $C^\infty$ (or  multivariate real analytical if necessary).
\begin{cases}
f_1(x_1, \cdots, x_n)  = 0\\
f_2(x_1, \cdots, x_n)  = 0\\
\cdots \\
f_{n-1}(x_1, \cdots, x_n)  = 0\\
\end{cases}

Suppose it is known that we can write the solution as $x_n = g(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1})$. My question is what can we say about the regularity of $g$? The first-order derivative seems to be  the implicit function theorem, but what about higher-order derivatives?

Comment: I thought the implicit function theorem had a generalization to higher derivatives? Then again , you may not be aware of this, or are you unsure of how to implement such a result, or how such a result would be precisely stated?